# Datatable no me muestra las tildes php

Tags: php, javascript, datatable

En el siguiente fragmento de codigo muestro la conexión que tengo actualmente en la datatable, el problema es que en localhost no me muestra las tildes sino que la reemplaza con "?" pero se vuelve peor al momento de subirlo al host ya que me lanza el siguiente error

[image: Error de datatable]

en el ssp.class.php tengo

```
static function sql_connect ( $sql_details )
    {
        try {
            $db = @new PDO(
                "mysql:host={$sql_details['host']};dbname={$sql_details['db']};charset=utf8",
                $sql_details['user'],
                $sql_details['pass'],
                array( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION )
            );
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            self::fatal(
                "An error occurred while connecting to the database. ".
                "The error reported by the server was: ".$e->getMessage()
            );
        }

        return $db;
    }
```

Y en server.php tengo

```
$columns = array(
    array( 'db' => 'cedula', 'dt' => 0 ),
    array( 'db' => 'nombre',  'dt' => 1 ),
    array( 'db' => 'apellido',   'dt' => 2 ),
    array( 'db' => 'agencia', 'dt' => 3,),
    array( 'db' => 'FechaIngreso','dt' => 4,)

);

// SQL server connection information
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => usuario,
    'pass' => clave,
    'db'   => bd,
    'host' => host,
);


/* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP
 * server-side, there is no need to edit below this line.
 */

require( 'vendor/DataTables/server-side/scripts/ssp.class.php' );

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple ( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns)
);
```

He intentado varias formas pero en localhost sigue trayendome el $ y en el host lanzandome el error, aclaro que tengo la base de datos en formato utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar los métodos `utf8_encode()` y `utf8_decode()` que tiene PHP.

Para codificar y enviar los valores:

```
<?php
    $cadena = utf8_encode("Este valor está codificado en UTF8");
?>
```

Para decodificar y mostrar el valor:

```
<?php
    echo utf8_decode($cadena);
?>
```